# Object moves back into origin everytime i open the blender file

Tags: transforms, scale, transform-orientation

[image]When i open the blender file the object seems to move back to origin and scales back down.... I tried to apply location but it gives me an error. Any idea whats happening or what can i do to fix it ?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491).If it gives you an error it would help if you add the information on that "error".

Comment: @cegaton just added photo !

Comment: Will it help using the Padlocks on the location when you hit N ?

Comment: Keep in mind that we now nothing else about your project, other that whatever you share on your post. There is no way to guess what you did or didn't do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a keyframe set on your object. That's why it moves back to original location and scales down.

You will need to open the N-Panel (see below) by hitting N and then right-click on any illumined fields and choose "Clear Keyframes"

[image: N-Panel Blender]

As for not being able to apply the location, your object is a multi-user (it shares data with other objects). You will need to make it a single user by clicking the number icon here:

[image: Make Single User - Blender]

I hope this helps!

-Adam

EDIT: Also, if there is appears to be no keyframes set and the object still jumps back to another location, it may be controlled by an NLA strip. Open the Non Linear Animation window and delete the action that is affecting it.

Comment: any chance on how to clear all keyframes at once? i have many meshes

Comment: Yes, you can use the dopesheet for this (Shift+F12 in Blender 2.8). Unselect the arrow icon if you want to see all objects (not just selected ones) and also check the ghost icon if you want to include channels from objects / bones that are not visible. Then you can box select the very top row of keys (in the "Summary" channel) which represent all the keys below and delete the ones you don't want. :-)

Comment: thank you so much man!!!

Comment: You are very welcome! :-)