# Blender 2.8. Random transforms several objects everytime I open a file

Tags: workflow, transforms

I've been working on a project for a few days now and after I exported an fbx Every time i open the project it takes several objects and gives them a seemingly random transform. I put all the objects back in place, saved several times, and then reopened the project and it had moved those same objects into the same places again. It did this in both projects (I have 2 Identical copies of the same project) I only exported from one of them. I know the save worked because I also deleted some things and they were still gone. Other than export I didn't change any setting between when it was working and broken. I don't have a clue whats happening so any help would be appreciated Thank you.

Comment: Also It broke one objects texturing (reset it to a single material that I wasn't using anymore I don't know where it got it from), and it reset the UV map on another. And it set the snapping grid to much smaller increments which I don't know how to reset.           I can also move other objects, save, and reopen and they stay where I put them. just not the couple its moved on it's own.

Comment: Regarding what is asked in your question - check if there are any keyframes. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141410/object-moves-back-into-origin-everytime-i-open-the-blender-file?rq=1. As to the mentioned in the comment that seems to be another problem which should be properly described in another question